# Store a Python output to a csv file?

Tags: python, excel, list, api, csv

I made this code where the purpose its to retrieve data from an API from a certain number of stock tickers

```py
    import requests
    import json
    import csv
    tickers = open("ticker_list.txt","r")
    for ticker in tickers:
        ticker = ticker.strip()
        url = "https://xxx/wallstreetbets/"+ticker
        headers = {'accept': 'application'}
        r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
        data = r.json()
        json_string = json.dumps(data, indent=1)
        for tick in data:
            print(tick ['Date'],tick['Mentions'])
```

This returns for every ticker an output like this

```
    2018-08-10 1
    2018-08-28 1
    2018-09-07 1
    2018-10-09 1
    2018-10-18 1
    2018-11-28 1
    2019-01-04 1
    2019-01-08 1
    2019-01-10 1
    2019-01-16 5
    2019-01-23 1
    2019-01-24 1
```

Where we have the date on the left, and the number of mentions on the right after a space.

What I want to do now is to store this result into a csv file where I have date, mentions in column so that when i open the csv file with excel I have:

```
    2018-08-10,1
    2018-08-28,1
    2018-09-07,1
    ...
```

Thanks in advance for the answers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Python3's [csv.writer()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.writer) function.

The given example looks like this:

```py
import csv
with open('eggs.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
    spamwriter = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=' ',
                            quotechar='|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
    spamwriter.writerow(['Spam'] * 5 + ['Baked Beans'])
    spamwriter.writerow(['Spam', 'Lovely Spam', 'Wonderful Spam'])
```

In your specific case you would write:

```py
import requests
import json
import csv
tickers = open("ticker_list.txt","r")
for ticker in tickers:
    ticker = ticker.strip()
    url = "https://xxx/wallstreetbets/"+ticker
    headers = {'accept': 'application'}
    r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    data = r.json()
    json_string = json.dumps(data, indent=1)
    
    # new code vvv
    with open("filename.csv", 'w', newline='') as csv_file:
        for tick in data:
            csv_writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
            csv_writer.writerow([tick['Date'], tick['Mentions']])
```

Comment: Works perfectly! (you missed a square braket at the end but thats ok), thanks a lot!!

Comment: Glad it works! Added the missing bracket too, thanks for pointing it out :)

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```py
import csv
.
.
.
with open('filename.csv', 'a+', newline='') as csvfile:
    fieldnames = ['Date', 'Mentions']
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames)

    for tick in data:
        writer.writerow({'Date': tick['Date'], 'Mentions': tick['Mentions']})
```